# Regex rematch character under some condition

Tags: java, regex

Consider an input string:

```
"Hi, I'm %name%. I pay 25% tax on my income. I live in %country%"
```

I want to replace `%name%`, and `%country%` each with `?`. The kicker is that I have to save the values in a list. For this example the expected output is:

```
"Hi, I'm ?. I pay 25% tax on my income. I live in ?"
```

With the list being `["name", "country"]`

Currently my implementation is like this:

```
String toTest = "Hi, I'm %name%. I pay 25% tax on my income. I live in %country%";

ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%(.*?)%");
Matcher m = p.matcher(toTest);
while(g)
{
    String g = m.group();
    switch(m.group())
    {
        case "%name%":
            al.add(name);
            toTest = toTest.replaceFirst("%name%", "?");
            break;
        case "%country%":
            al.add(country);
            toTest = toTest.replaceFirst("%country%", "?");
            break;
    }
}

String[] sa = al.toArray(new String[]{});
System.out.println(toTest);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sa));
```

This test case breaks it. The actual output is:

```
Hi, I'm ?. I pay 25% tax on my income. I live in %country%  
["name"]
```

What I want is that in my loop, if the group doesn't match anything in the switch statement, then I want to use the last "%" as part of check. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your problem lies in `(.*?)` part of your regex `%(.*?)%` which lets it match parts like

```
"Hi, I'm %name%. I pay 25% tax on my income. I live in %country%";
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Consider using `%(\\w+)%` to accept only alphanumeric characters between `%`.
Also if you know which words you want to replace you can just use something like

```
%(name|country)%
```

Another improvement could be using `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` from `Matcher` class which will replace currently found match with another value instead of `replaceFirst` which needs to iterate from beginning to find matched part so your code could look like

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "?");
        al.add(m.group(1));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    toTest = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Yes, I knew that was the problem. Matching alphanums may be a good idea actually. I actually probably just need alphas. This works for the current example, and any forseeable examples that I can think of atm. Out of curiosity sake, it would be nice to get an answer to my last sentence, or if it's even possible

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your last question correctly "*What I want is that in my loop, if the group doesn't match anything in the switch statement, then I want to use the last "%" as part of check.*". Could you give some example? Some input and expected result (preferably described why it is expected).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
"%(\w+)%"
```

in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%(\\w+)%");
```

Your Java code code can be **hugely simplified** too:

```
String toTest = "Hi, I'm %name%. I pay 25% tax on my income. I live in %country%";
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%(\\w+)%");
Matcher m = p.matcher(toTest);
while(m.find()) {
    al.add(m.group(1));
    toTest = toTest.replaceFirst(m.group(0), "?");
}

System.out.println(toTest);
System.out.println(al);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Hi, I'm ?. I pay 25% tax on my income. I live in ?
[name, country]
```

Comment: The simplification  you made, I was strictly trying to avoid. Since in that case it would have replaced "% tax on my income. I live in %" in my string with `?`. I wanted to verify that the string that it matched is something that I want to remove. I'm still not 100% sure if "%(\w+)%" is sufficient for me or not.

Comment: The example that I gave was extremely simplified as well.

Comment: As you can see from above results that `25%` is not matching the regex. It is better to avoid `.*` (to avoid seriously flawed matches as you encountered). If you want you can add more acceptable character in `\w` like `[\w.-]` etc.